# Status of Bullet's soft-body dynamics integration

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was wondering how far the integration efforts of Bullet's soft-body dynamics into Gazebo have come? This task seems to have disappeared from the [Roadmap](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Roadmap), but I was unable to find anything related in any current Gazebo source code.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5129/status-of-bullet%27s-soft-body-dynamics-integration/) by [jir-tobi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/591/jir-tobi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We are in the process of implementing many features in Gazebo. Bullet's soft-body dynamics are on our minds, though there is not yet a feature request for it on the [Gazebo issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues?status=new&status=open). Please feel free to submit one and vote for it.

As a side note, we are actively working to implement deformable body physics using the [DART physics engine](https://github.com/dartsim/dart). Currently we have [added some sdf parameters](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/issue/32/add-deformable-properties-to-sdf) and are working with the DART developers on the implementation.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jir-tobi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/591/jir-tobi/) on 2013-12-19**:
Thanks for the update, I'll keep an eye on the development also of DART.

**Comment by [liangfok](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/51/liangfok/) on 2015-02-04**:
Any update on Gazebo's ability to simulate deformable objects?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2015-02-04**:
There has been some work done with DART soft body, though it hasn't been merged into any release branches yet. Also we need to [implement rendering of deformable bodies](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/981/rendering-deformable-meshes). There's also a [general feature request about soft body support](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1422/soft-body-supoort-in-gazebo).